# AWS cognito userpools JavaScript SDK get user's policy documents

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

For a registered user in AWS Cognito Userpools, is it possible to retrieve the policy documents attached to the user through IAM roles through JavaScript SDK?

The user case is to write a custom authorizer which authorize cognito id token and return the policy document with the IAM permission, user is capable of assuming through Cognito User Groups.

Comment: How are you planning to use the policy document, that might lead to solution(s)?

Comment: I'm planning to use it for API Gateway Resource Authorization. Ideally its more of a combination of CognitoAuthorizer and IAMAuthorizer for API Gateway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After carrying out further research, following approach is used to retrieve 'inline policies' attached to the user through IAM roles.

- From AWS Cognito JWT, extract role names from ARNs and using IAM SDK for JavaScript get the policy ARNs by using

  ```
  const aws = require('aws-sdk');
  let iam = new aws.IAM();
  iam.listRolePolicies({ RoleName: roleName }, function (err, data) {
      let policyNames = data["PolicyNames"];
      // Use policy names and role names to retrieve policy documents
  });
  ```
- Using policy names and role names in combination, retrieve the policy documents in JSON format

  ```
  iam.getRolePolicy({ PolicyName: policyName, RoleName: roleName }, 
  function (err, data) {
      let document = decodeURIComponent(data["PolicyDocument"]);
  });
  ```
- Next iteratively extract the statements from each policy document and build a single one.

Example code could be found in [this](https://github.com/99xt/cognito-iam-authorizer) github repository.