# Serverless Framework with server-side authentication and Cognito

Tags: rest, authentication, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework

I have already implemented various REST-APIs using the Serverless Framework with APIG, DynamoDB as data storage and Cognito for user authentication with Angular2 as frontend. The functions can easily be secured by a Cognito authorizer on the server-side. The downside is that I have to integrate AWS SDK in my frontend applications in order to authenticate the user with Cognito first (signup/signin, ...). I could also use the AWS_IAM authorizer but then I also have to sign all requests on the client side with an [AWS specific signature](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html) before sending the request to the API Gateway.

Now I was wondering if there is any possibility to keep authentication and authorization on the server side, so I can use an open standard like [JSON Web Tokens](https://jwt.io) for signup/signin? This would allow me to open my REST-API for other developers as well **without forcing them to use Cognito** at all.

I know that one possibility would be to implement a custom authorizer for my lambda functions but isn't there anything stable, which can be used "out-of-the-box" already? Most of the examples I found are using Cognito or IAM auth AWS signature signin on client side (e.g. [serverless-stack.com](http://serverless-stack.com/chapters/connect-to-api-gateway-with-iam-auth.html)).

It is curious that I didn't find any useful informations about this on the web so far, since I think that this is a typical use case for REST APIs. Or do I have a conceptual misunderstanding about API Gateway + Cognito?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been through the same trouble in understanding the way how AWS Cognito works and what options are available to implement authentication & authorization. Unfortunately there is no **out-of-the-box** method available to do it for your requirement. Nevertheless let's hope that Amazon comes up with a feature very soon.

Basically, there are 3 options available to implement authentication.

1. AWS_IAM
2. Cognito Authorizer
3. Custom Authorizer

### AWS_IAM

In addition to authentication, this method can be used to implement authorization using IAM Roles or IAM Users easily. The only downside of it is that you need to send a request signed with an **aws-signature-4** which is not the standard way that we have seen in IDP services like Auth0.

### Cognito Authorizer

This method meets the expectation of sending a JWT token with API requests. You can create users in Cognito User Pool and then use it to authenticate and generate an IdToken. However, this method will only allow you to authenticate users; authorization needs to be handled in method level.

### Custom Authorizer

This method can be used to write your own way of authentication and authorization. Also it helps to eliminate writing authorization logic in API methods. The ideal solution would be to use AWS Cognito User Pool to authenticate users and then generate a policy document for IAM Role to access resources.
Here is an example [AWS cognito userpools JavaScript SDK get user's policy documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45070378/aws-cognito-userpools-javascript-sdk-get-users-policy-documents).
Also keep in mind that this solution will be invoking an extra lambda function for each request that you make.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Cognito Auth to Server-side. Following would be the steps.

Implementing Sign-up and Sign-in

- Implement Sign-up form in the frontend and API Gateway endpoint(e.g /register) using Lambda to receive, the Sign-up data, which will create user in Cognito using AWS SDK. For detailed reference check [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples.html) link.

  ```
  AWSCognito.config.region = 'us-east-1'; //This is required to derive the endpoint

  var poolData = { UserPoolId : 'us-east-1_TcoKGbf7n',
      ClientId : '4pe2usejqcdmhi0a25jp4b5sh3'
  };
  var userPool = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(poolData);

  var attributeList = [];

  var dataEmail = {
      Name : 'email',
      Value : 'email@mydomain.com'
  };
  var dataPhoneNumber = {
      Name : 'phone_number',
      Value : '+15555555555'
  };
  var attributeEmail = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserAttribute(dataEmail);
  var attributePhoneNumber = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserAttribute(dataPhoneNumber);

  attributeList.push(attributeEmail);
  attributeList.push(attributePhoneNumber);

  userPool.signUp('username', 'password', attributeList, null, function(err, result){
      if (err) {
          alert(err);
          return;
      }
      cognitoUser = result.user;
      console.log('user name is ' + cognitoUser.getUsername());
  });
  ```
- Do similarly for the Sign-in by creating an frontend & API Gateway endpoint(e.g /login)

  ```
  var authenticationData = {
      Username : 'username',
      Password : 'password'
  };
  var authenticationDetails = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);
  var poolData = { UserPoolId : 'us-east-1_TcoKGbf7n',
      ClientId : '4pe2usejqcdmhi0a25jp4b5sh3'
  };
  var userPool = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
  var userData = {
     Username : 'username',
     Pool : userPool
  };
  var cognitoUser = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUser(userData);
     cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
        onSuccess: function (result) {
           console.log('access token + ' + result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken());
       /* Use the idToken for Logins Map when Federating User Pools with Cognito Identity or when passing through an Authorization Header to an API Gateway Authorizer */
      console.log('idToken + ' + result.idToken.jwtToken);
     },
     onFailure: function(err) {
        alert(err);
     },
  });
  ```

Storing and sending the JWT from your Browser and Validating at API Gateway.

- After receiving the JWT from the Sign-in API endpoint, you can store it locally in user's browser, using HTML5 Localstorage, Sessionstorage or Client Side Cookie. Optionally if you need to use Server Side Cookies, it will require to have a Proxy backend which keeps the Session state with the Web App and Convert it to the JWT to invoke the API Gateway.
- From the Web Browser(Assuming your client directly invokes API Gateway) set a HTTP header called Authorization and forward the JWT to the API Gateway invocations.
- At API Gateway use Cognito Authorizer to as the Authorize the token where it will also forward the user identity resolved to your Lambdas.

Note: Here I have purposefully avoided the IAM Authorization since it will require some additional work from Web App JavaScripts to implement [Signature 4 Signing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html)  at Browser and also requires to refresh the token frequently which is straightforward with AWS JavaScript SDKs but will become complex if you need to implement it on your own.

Comment: Could you provide the npm location of module that you used (AWSCognito). Thanks

Comment: new AWSCognito...... In there, you mean AWSCognito is 'aws-sdk'. Thanks

Comment: AWS recently shared a library called AWS Amplify which simplify the authentication. https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify

Comment: Ashan, thanks for your reply. I am new to nodejs and aws ecosystem. It is a little bit difficult to understand amplify within a short amount of time. I just want to follow your code. Are you using 'amazon-cognito-identity-js' or 'amazon-cognito-identity-js-node' module? AWSCognito means require('aws-sdk');. Thanks

Comment: As user Ashan mentioned in the comments, AWS Amplify can be used. 
Have a look here, there is an authentication guide that covers the whole process.
[AWS Amplify Authentication Guide](https://aws.github.io/aws-amplify/media/authentication_guide)

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this [here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-auth-reference-app).

The example demonstrates various configurations that include custom authorizers, cognito, lambda, dynamoDB etc.